# Why getting nil when iterating through firebase database?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm struggling with my firebase db and i don't know, what i'm doing wrong.

```
self.ref.child("User").observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in

    let value = snapshot.value as! [String: AnyObject]

    for each in value {
        let username = each.value["username"] as! String
        self.ref.child("Highscores").child(username).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
            let wert = snapshot.value as! [String: AnyObject]
            for each in wert {
                let fbscore = each.value["score"] as! String
```

In this case, fbscore is nil.

The output (print) of each is ("score", 21), so each.key is "score" and each.value is "21".

Where is my mistake? I didn't see anything.

Comment: `let fbscore = each.value as! Int`

Comment: Haha, thank you... that was too easy. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to Downcast `AnyObject` to correct type `Int` not `String`.

```
each.value as! Int
```

As well as to prevent nil exceptions.Use `guard` or optional Binding.

```
if let fbscore = each.value as? Int {      
    print(fbscore)
}else{
   print("casting failed")
}
```